# ARKit nodes dissapear after sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin transformation

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, location, transform

I have some code that is comprised of the delegate method for obtaining a heading, and a transformation. I take the heading and turn it into radians and use the angle to rotate around the y-axis:

```
    ┌                             ┐
Y = |  cos(ry)    0   sin(ry)   0 |
    |  0          1   0         0 |
    |  -sin(ry)   0   cos(ry)   0 |
    |  0          0   0         1 |
    └                             ┘
```

[What are the first two columns in SCNMatrix4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264518/what-are-the-first-two-columns-in-scnmatrix4)

code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        print("received heading: \(String(describing: newHeading))")
        self.currentHeading = newHeading
        print("\(Float(currentHeading.trueHeading)) or for magneticHeading: \(currentHeading.magneticHeading)")
        let headingInRadians = degreesToRadians(deg: Float(currentHeading.trueHeading))
        print("\(headingInRadians) -------- headingInRadians")

        var m = matrix_float4x4()
        m.columns.3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
        m.columns.2 = [sin(headingInRadians), 0.0, cos(headingInRadians), 0.0]
        m.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        m.columns.0 = [cos(headingInRadians), 0.0, -sin(headingInRadians), 0.0]

        sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: m)
    }
```

It is removing all the nodes when I call `setWorldOrigin`. I have tried pausing the session, running the function, and then starting the session again, and I get this weird wonky low fps, low light situation. I know it is the function call to `setWorldOrigin` because when I remove it I see the nodes and they persist.

**UPDATE**

Ive been working on this...I am debugging by simply trying to change the scale by 2...all I should see happen is the nodes I have placed in a grid should spread out...however I am still getting the same result. After trying to `setWorldOrigin` the nodes are removed. Does using this function reset something? Is there a special place I am supposed to use it? (some delegate function)?

**UPDATE**

`print("\(sceneView.scene.rootNode) --- rootNode in renderer")` produces:

```
<SCNNode: 0x1c01f8100 | 111 children> --- rootNode in renderer
```

So it appears that the `rootNode` and its `children` are still somewhere...but where are they going with such a simple and small transformation?

**UPDATE**

`print("\(sceneView.scene.rootNode.position) --- rootNode in renderer")` produces:

```
SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0) --- rootNode in renderer
```

Yet...I see none of the children...so the rootNode appears to be somewhere else.

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that the transform is not happening...the positioning of the childnodes (that I can't see) is still the same as its original state (a node every 2 grid blocks (meters) i.e.:

```
SCNVector3(x: 6.0, y: 0.0, z: -4.0) --- rootNode child node
SCNVector3(x: 6.0, y: 0.0, z: -2.0) --- rootNode child node
```

**UPDATE**

The narrowest view of this problem I have now is that even a simple rotate removes the nodes from view...since there is no position change...this means that something is going on with the rendering process I believe.

```
func viewDidLoad() {    

    ...

    sceneView.scene = scene
    view.addSubview(sceneView)

    let angle = coordinateConverter.getUprightMKMapCameraHeading()
    print("\(angle) --- angle")

    mRotate = matrix_float4x4()
    mRotate.columns.3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    mRotate.columns.2 = [Float(sin(angle)), 0.0, Float(cos(angle)), 0.0]
    mRotate.columns.1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    mRotate.columns.0 = [Float(cos(angle)), 0.0, Float(-sin(angle)), 0.0]

    sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: mRotate)
```

console output:

```
281.689248803283 --- angle
```

Still, the virtual objects remain invisible, but placed at the origin...which should still be the same.

I also should note that the standard 1,1,1,1 transform DOES work...but obviously, it does nothing...but I guess just using the function doesn't make them disappear...they only disappear if your transform actually does something...

```
...

var identity = matrix_float4x4()
identity.columns.3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
identity.columns.2 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
identity.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
identity.columns.0 = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: identity)

...
```

The above transforms nothing...and the nodes remain in view.

If I change the matrix to this (translate by 10,10):

```
var identity = matrix_float4x4()
identity.columns.3 = [10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 1.0]
identity.columns.2 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
identity.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
identity.columns.0 = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

It works...

I'm just thinking... do I have to scale my world down (real-world MKMapKit coordinates/unit) maybe because the hardware can't handle a world that is scaled. Also, from the above test...I think I realized that the origin moves when you use this function, but the nodes do not, so If I want the nodes to remain at my position after the transform...and I need to transform them back. Still, the result is the same:

```
print("\(transformerFromPDFToMk.tx) -- tx")
print("\(transformerFromPDFToMk.ty) -- ty")

m = matrix_float4x4()
m.columns.3 = [Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.tx), 0.0, Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.ty), 1.0]
m.columns.2 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
m.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
m.columns.0 = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: m)

for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    node.position = SCNVector3Make(-Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.tx) + node.position.x, node.position.y, Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.ty) + node.position.z)
}
```

console output:

```
81145547.3824476 -- tx
99399579.5362287 -- ty
```

**UPDATE**

I SEE MY OBJECTS (kind of)! I thought I had tried this before...but its working a little better now -
 the code package I used defined a scale (`coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters`)...and I was converting to it improperly. But...they are flickering in and out rapidly...

```
m = matrix_float4x4()
m.columns.3 = [Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.tx) / Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters), 0.0, Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.ty) / Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters), 1.0]
m.columns.2 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
m.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
m.columns.0 = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: m)

sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: m)

for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    node.position = SCNVector3Make(-Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.tx) / 
       Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters) + node.position.x / 
       Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters), node.position.y / 
       Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters), -
       Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.ty) / 
       Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters) + node.position.z / 
       Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters))
}
```

**UPDATE**

Is the flickering "z-fighting"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After resolving the scaling issues, I reduced the size of the world (scale) and put the objects a little further apart from each other (to fix the flickering/"z-fighting") - wikipedia's page was very helpful, I'm pretty sure all I needed to do was reduce the world size.

Answer (score 0):

Hey After looking through your code, I noticed that you have the 4x4 matrix set up wrong for a rotation around the y-axis.

You currently have.

```
var m = matrix_float4x4()
m.columns.3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
m.columns.2 = [sin(headingInRadians), 0.0, cos(headingInRadians), 0.0]
m.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
m.columns.0 = [cos(headingInRadians), 0.0, -sin(headingInRadians), 0.0]
```

The correct format is below based on the exchange:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72014/given-an-angle-in-radians-how-could-i-calculate-a-4x4-rotation-matrix-about-the

```
var m = matrix_float4x4()
m.columns.3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
m.columns.2 = [-sin(headingInRadians), 0.0, cos(headingInRadians), 0.0]
m.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
m.columns.0 = [cos(headingInRadians), 0.0, sin(headingInRadians), 0.0]
```

This should make it work for you.

Depending on what you want to do with your scene I recommend taking the difference between the current heading and previous heading and using that as your angle. This should theoretically have it so that the scene is always facing the same direction for you.